# Why do males have more birth defects?

Tags: genetics

I taught in elementary school for 20 years and noticed that males were far more likely to be classified as handicapped than females.
More males than females die at birth and are more likely to have birth defects. Why?

Comment: Do you have a reference that supports these claims?

Comment: I guess you mean "taught" elementary school. I am taking the liberty to edit that. However, you have to provide or cite a well documented data for making such a claim.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Biology.SE Wendy.

**Issue in your post**

There are a few issues in your post.

1. You made a personal observation that males tend to more often be diagnosed with a handicap than females (in frequency). You probably did not keep track of the numbers and you probably did not make any statistical analysis. So there is really no reason to trust this observation. The idea that males are more often classified as handicapped than females is opinion-based for the moment and you will need a reference for this before asking why it is true.
2. You also claim that most birth defects occur in males and not in females. You should also include a reference.
3. You are talking about gender difference in "handicap frequency" and "birth defect frequency". It is a little unclear what the question (your last sentence `Why`) refers to. Maybe both. In such case, why would you expect that a common mechanism explains both observations? You should probably restrict your question to one or the other only.

For these above reasons, the question cannot be correctly answered in its above form. But below is something that may already help you.

**Birth defects**

It is true that birth defects is more prevalent among males than among females (in humans). According to [Lary and Paulozzi 2001](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11745830):

> The overall prevalence of major defects at birth was 3.9% among males and 2.8% among females.

Reading their abstract only, one can see that they go on saying

> Defects of the sex organs were eight and one-half times more prevalent among males and accounted for about half of the increased risk of birth defects among males relative to females. Urinary tract defects were 62% more prevalent among males, and gastrointestinal tract defects were 55% more prevalent among males.

In consequence, it seems at first sight that the difference in birth defects frequency is very much related to the development of sex organs. In their abstract they announce that they discuss the mechanisms that account for such difference.

I currently don't have access to the paper (I am not on campus) to report more details of their findings.

Answer (score 0):

Although this isn't the determining factor in why males have more birth defects but it should be noted that the the fact males have only one X chromosome means they are very susceptible to X-linked recessive diseases.

As females receive two X chromosomes the chance of them obtaining an X-linked recessive disease is reduced significantly.

(And not all X-linked diseases produce cognitive impairment in individuals but if you sift through all the X-linked diseases it is easy to see the relationship.)